# Why is the Spherical Bessel Function acting strangely at this point?

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I'm doing some computation that requires the use of [Spherical Bessel Functions of the 1st kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), at high orders and values.

So, I managed to find this, while running it over a wide range of values. I hit an unexpected 0:

```
In[209]:= SphericalBesselJ[210, (1/1.5)*2*Pi*1.5*1000/40] // InputForm

Out[209]//InputForm=
0.
```

For explaining this, (1/1.5)*2*Pi*1.5*1000/40 is about 157.08.

That was strange to me, so I plotted it from 157 to 157.1. It looks smooth, no crazy behavior or zeros.

Trying it slightly on either side of this supposed 0:

```
In[212]:= SphericalBesselJ[210, (1/1.5)*2*Pi*1.5*1000/40 - .0001] // InputForm

Out[212]//InputForm=
9.476205413946214*^-16


In[213]:= SphericalBesselJ[210, (1/1.5)*2*Pi*1.5*1000/40 + .0001] // InputForm

Out[213]//InputForm=
9.477897706291978*^-16
```

In fact, I just realized that it does the same thing for all n (the first argument) greater than 200. I can't find anything on [the Mathematica page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalBesselJ.html) for this function... am I missing something obvious, like I usually am?

thanks!

edit: Some further poking has revealed that I can also get it to work for n = 71 (for some different values of the second argument). I'm very confused now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SphericalBesselJ[210, (1/1.5)*2*Pi*1.5*1000/40] // InputForm
```

> 0.

Use higher precision input

```
SphericalBesselJ[210, (1/1.5`20)*2*Pi*1.5`20*1000/40] // InputForm
```

> 9.4770515229477837927439`0.13632911832271324*^-16

```
SphericalBesselJ[210, (2/3)*2*Pi*(3/2)*1000/40] // N[#, 20] & // InputForm
```

> 9.47705152294778379274395028349340334928589`20.*^-16

```
SphericalBesselJ[210, Rationalize[(1/1.5)*2*Pi*1.5*1000/40, 0]] // 
  N[#, 20] & // InputForm
```

> 9.477051522947880778530041024948616289348122`20.*^-16

```
Plot[SphericalBesselJ[210, k], {k, 156, 158}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 PlotPoints -> 51]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing to the documentation of `SetPrecision`. (+1).

Comment: Ahhh, thank you, I should have known. I've been tricked by this before, but I thought I was being careful, checking with InputForm. But I'm still a little confused, why is it going to 0? Why do we find some anomalous point like that?

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html  "In most cases, built-in Wolfram Language functions will give you results that have as much precision as can be justified on the basis of your input.  ...  If you give higher-precision input, the Wolfram Language will use higher precision in its internal calculations, and you will usually be able to get a higher-precision result." You gave very low precision inputs and the resulting precision only justified a `0.` result.